# Is there a data structure like a list with no duplicates that still allows indexing?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I can't use a HashSet because I still need enumeration. If you're wondering why I need this, this is why:

```
private List<Point> sanitize(List<Point> crossPoints) {
    HashSet<int> indexesToDelete = new HashSet<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < crossPoints.Count(); i++) {
        if ((crossPoints[i].X - crossPoints[i + 1].X) <= 4) {
            indexesToDelete.Add(i);
            indexesToDelete.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < crossPoints.Count(); i++) {
        if ((crossPoints[i].Y - crossPoints[i + 1].Y) <= 4) {
            indexesToDelete.Add(i);
            indexesToDelete.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < indexesToDelete.Count; i++) {
        crossPoints.RemoveAt(indexesToDelete[i]);
    }

    return crossPoints;
}
```

This won't compile because of `indexesToDelete[i]`

Comment: Have you tried using indexesToDelete.elementAt(i) ?

Comment: Watch out for the way you are deleting `Point`s. Unless you are removing the last `Point` in the list, the indexes will change.

Comment: @MAV: Oh wow, nice catch. I just spent a minute debugging it and you clarify shortly after.

Comment: In this case you don't need indexing, just enumeration. You can enumerate over hashsets using a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the `HashSet` you can do:

```
foreach(int i in indexesToDelete) 
{
    ...
```

But be careful when you delete items with `RemoveAt`! If you are not deleting the last entry, some of the other items will be moved and therefore get a new index.

One way to do this would be to sort the indexes and remove items from the highest to the lowest index.

```
var indexes = indexesToDelete.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
foreach (int i in indexes)
{
    crossPoints.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

---

You could also use [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of `HashSet`.

```
SortedSet<int> indexesToDelete = new SortedSet<int>();
...

foreach(int i in indexesToDelete.Reverse())
{
    crossPoints.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: This strikes me as a particularly bad idea. The order of enumeration of any hashtable based collection is **not** guaranteed. Relying on such behaviour creates code that has non-guaranteed behaviour. Just because it *seems* to work isn't good enough. Hovering over the downvote...

Comment: @spender I am not relying on the order of the HashSet. `OrderByDescending` creates a sorted view of the HashSet, which is converted to a list. Correct, you should not rely on the order of a HashSet, which is why I do not recommend the first approach (and the fact that the indexes will be messed up). An alternative to my solution would be `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [OrderedDictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); however, it is not generic. The `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` [Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is generic. Note the difference between orderd and sorted. Ordered means that your insert order is kept intact. Sorted means that the insert order is ignored in favor of a sorting order.